# How can I see locked data in tables by a specific transaction?

Tags: mysql, transactions

I have a transaction in `information_schema.INNODB_TRX` which is locking a specific rows of a table.

How can I see that rows?

Or in other hand, how can I see all data locked?

**INNODB_TRX**

- trx_id :   14529346291
- trx_state :    RUNNING
- trx_started :  2019-03-11 06:21:13
- trx_requested_lock_id :    NULL
- trx_wait_started : NULL
- trx_weight :   5
- trx_mysql_thread_id :  1423062
- trx_query :    NULL
- trx_operation_state :  NULL
- trx_tables_in_use :    0
- trx_tables_locked :    0
- trx_lock_structs : 3
- trx_lock_memory_bytes :    360
- trx_rows_locked :  1
- trx_rows_modified :    2
- trx_concurrency_tickets :  0
- trx_isolation_level :  READ COMMITTED
- trx_unique_checks :    1
- trx_foreign_key_checks :   1
- trx_last_foreign_key_error :   NULL
- trx_adaptive_hash_latched :    0
- trx_adaptive_hash_timeout :    9998
- trx_is_read_only : 0
- trx_autocommit_non_locking :   0

**PROCESSLIST**

- ID :   1423062
- USER : *********
- HOST : ********
- DB :   ********
- COMMAND :  Sleep
- TIME : 16628
- STATE :
- INFO : NULL

Transaction 14529346291 has been running 5 hours, but processlist is `Sleep`

Comment: *"How can I see that rows?"* Other then reading `trx_query` column and parsing the query and modifiy it to get the id's or query type meaning converting `UPDATE` and `DELETE`  to a `SELECT`.. Short answer **Non**

Comment: The real question is why do you want to know it or why are you going to need this?

Comment: Thanks Raymond, but my problem is that processlist is sleep, but transaction is open, so `trx_query` is null

Comment: I'm trying find the query who don't close the transaction, and maby see locked rows can help me

Comment: Not sure what you mean.. Can you post the results of the `processlist` and `information_schema.INNODB_TRX` here so we can understand what going on? And you MysQL version? With `SELECT VERSION()`

Comment: have you look the output from **SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;**

Comment: *"I'm trying find the query who don't close the transaction"* That will be pretty hard without a query in `trx_query`

Comment: I added the info of both tables that are problematic

Comment: Oh that seams just to be session/connection which isnt `disconnected` from  application code or SQL IDE.. You can kill the processid

Comment: Maybe you should configure the `wait_timeout` variable lower so MySQL automaticlly kills those improper disconnected (sleep) threads alot sooner..

Comment: That session/connection have data locked, and when I try updathe some of this rows, it's produces a lock_wait
Yes, I thought down the `wait_timeout`, but now I'm trying find why it occurs